# CDbCriteria conditions and params

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

This is the first time I try to use CDbCriteria so I should have a concept error, I have the next function in the class AsistenciasUtils:

```
public function getCodigoTecnico()
{
//  $id=null;
$codigos=new CDbCriteria;
$codigos->select='codigo';
$codigos->condition='id=:id';
$codigos->params=array(':id'=>$id);

$listaCodigos=CHtml::listdata(Tecnicos::model()->findAll($codigos),'id','codigo');

return $listaCodigos;

}
```

That's used in _form in this lines.

```
<div class="span4">

    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'n_asistencia'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($model,'n_asistencia',array('disabled'=>true, 'value'=>AsistenciasUtils::getNumeroAsistencia(),)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'n_asistencia'); ?>
</div>
```

I have read lots of web sites that mades something similar in order to use CDbCriteria, but in this case.

a) If I don't write paramas=array() the result is next error
"*CDbCommand falló al ejecutar la sentencia // fails to exectute the sentence SQL: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT codigo FROM `asistencias_tecnicos` `t` WHERE id=:id*"

b) If I add params line I recive this error in the body of aplication "*Error 500
Undefined variable: id*" (this is very surprising for me)

c) if I change the $id variable by a number it works but I obtain only one register.

I don't undestand what is exactly params (in a SQL sentence)

And one more thing, when I don't have an error (and recive only one register), this message apears in the body of the _form.
[image: SQL sentence in the middel of the body]

I don't undestand what is wrong. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have two observations, first off, add 'id' to your select, mate; i.e. `$codigos->select = array('id', 'codigo');` or `$codigos->select = 'id, codigo'`, you're telling `CHtml::listData` to use `'id'` for the indexes, but you didn't select it. Second, I recommend you use `$codigos->compare('id', $id);` instead of modifying the params part, thus letting `CDbCriteria` handle your params internally, this is less error prone; i.e. 
`$codigos = new CDbCriteria();
$codigos->select = array('id', 'codigo');
$codigos->compare('id', $id);`.
Oh, and make sure $id is defined beforehand. Hope it helps.

Comment: First the message in the _form was my fault, due to a comment whithout // sorry. Second